# R apply family - synchronizing between invocations

Tags: r

Consider:

```
lapply(1:10, FUN = function(a) {
  // Do some calculation here
  // Now store result in an external file
})
```

Storing to this external file involves using a thirdparty library for a file format in which I can't access the same file simultaneously, like from two threads.

It seems that lapply() simply loops sequentially underneath, and writing to my file hasn't failed/corrupted anything so far; on the other hand, maybe it's just a coincidence or I'm not detecting errors in anything more complex than my simple test cases. So my question is, how do I synchronize between invocations of FUN, so that I can wait with writing to the file until another FUN is done with it? Essentially I want to put the part where it's storing 
results in a critical section.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"synchronizing different lambda's"* ?

Comment: I've edited to something that's hopefully clearer?

Comment: u should probably define what u want in the function's logic, however your question is still too general to give any meaningful answer.

Comment: Well I want to put a lock on a resource in the lambda, to synchronize access to that resource between the instantiated lambdas. I'm not sure how to explain differently, that description is about as clear as possible. One needs know to know what a 'critical section' and a 'lock' is, and what 'synchronize' means in the context of concurrent programming, and what a lambda is - but I doubt that anyone who wouldn't know that could answer this question. So if this is a terminology problem, please point me to what exactly it is you don't understand.